# UWP Windows-10 Cannot add Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to my C# app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package, windows-10-universal

I have a C# app targeting windows UWP. It was all working fine couple month's ago. When I opened it today, it cannot find this reference: **Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform**. I am unable to install this reference as well. Here are my project details & the steps I have followed:

 My VS details:

```
  MS VS Professional 2015
  Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
  Microsoft .NET Framework
  Version 4.6.01038
```

When I try to install this reference: **Referencs(right click)->Manage NuGet Packages**, & then by selecting **Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform**, I get this error:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I have **NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015 Version 3.4.3.855** installed. 

 Based on the suggestion available here [Github MS UWP samples page](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/104) I deleted **project.json** from my project, but that doesnt seem to help me. Unfortunately I do not see **project.lock.json** file in my project

Comment: Can you share your current csproj and project.json contents?

Comment: Hi @HarikrishnaMenonA, Thanks for the response. I am not sure how to share these files on stack overflow. Please let me know any alternate way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar exception after copy solution folder to other machine.
In **project.lock.json** in field "*packageFolders*" and "*project*" where my settings for previse machine, I have changed them and it resolve my issue