# UWP Windows-10 VS-2015 doesnt auto generate project.lock.json file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, windows-10-universal, project.json

I am trying to run my UWP app on Windows-10 with Visual Studio 2015. The issue is, VS-2015 doesnt seem to generate this hidden file **project.lock.json**

Since this file is not generated, I hit this error: [Nuget Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398916/uwp-windows-10-cannot-add-microsoft-netcore-universalwindowsplatform-to-my-c-sha)

***The workaround which I am using is to create an new empty project and copy the two json files to your existing project.***

This is my VS-2015 details:

> MS VS Professional 2015
>   
> Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
>   
> Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.6.01038

Comment: Can you check your setting to see if downloading packages is enabled? What do you mean by copying the *two* json files? project.json should be there already, and only project.lock.json is generated.

Comment: Hi @YishaiGalatzer, Thanks for the response. Yes the **project.json** is already available. I just copy both the files (project.json & project.lock.json) from the empty project. How to check if _**downloading packages**_ is enabled or not ?

Comment: Did you try to restore packages?

Comment: Hi @svick,Thx for the response. I was not sure how to _restore packages_ in VS-2015. I found these two SO links : [Link-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131095/how-to-enable-nugets-package-restore-in-visual-studio-2015) & [Link-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895504/how-do-i-enable-nuget-package-restore-in-visual-studio-2015)
Based on the answers available on the above mentioned threads, I enabled the checkbox under **Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources**
Still it doesnt seem to resolve my issue. Kindly let me know, in case  if I missed anything.

Comment: Right click on the project in Solution Explorer and select Restore Packages.

Comment: Can you share both your project.json and the actual errors you are getting.

Comment: Hi @svick, Thanks for the response. restoring packages seems to do the trick. After I restore package, I see the **project.lock.json** file & solve my issue. The problem, now though, is that everytime I open my solution/project I need to restore packages. Is there a way to configure VS such that it automatically does this everytime whenever I open the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to ***Right click on the project in Solution Explorer and select Restore Packages***

Thanks @svick for the solution